# How to add default constructor in SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: android

My app works fine but when I try to generate signed APK I get this error in my messages.

```
Error:Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (com.example.emilythacker.myapplication.MyDBHandler) [Instantiatable]
```

When I add the empty constructor

```
 public MyDBHandler(){}
```

to my code I get this error instead

```
    Error:(18, 25) error: no suitable constructor found for SQLiteOpenHelper(no arguments)
constructor SQLiteOpenHelper.SQLiteOpenHelper(Context,String,CursorFactory,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor SQLiteOpenHelper.SQLiteOpenHelper(Context,String,CursorFactory,int,DatabaseErrorHandler) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Here is my MyDBHelper.class

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

public MyDBHandler(){

}

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

//add a new row to the database
public void addProduct(Products product){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_PRODUCTS) <= 4){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    else{
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        deleteProduct();
        db.close();
    }
}

//code coming from MainActivity
public void addButtonClicked(String highscore1){
    Products product = new Products(highscore1);
    addProduct(product);
    updateDatabase();
}

//code coming from MainActivity
public void updateDatabase(){
        String dbString = databaseToString();
        MainActivity.productText.setText(dbString);
}

//delete a product from the database
public void deleteProduct(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM products WHERE _id NOT IN"+
                //only reading first digit of double digit numbers
               //" (SELECT _id FROM products ORDER BY  productname DESC LIMIT 5)");
            //this runs but isnt putting double digit scores into the high score textView
            " (SELECT _id FROM products ORDER BY CAST(productname AS NUMBER) DESC LIMIT 5)");


}


//print out the database as a string
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";


    //Cursor point to location in your results
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, null, null, null, null, COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME +" DESC");
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();

    }


    db.close();
    return dbString;

}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: post your MyDbHelper code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Android Lint error that only gets checked on release builds.  If you have MyDBHandler declared in your Android Manifest you need to delete it as it is not an activity and does not need to be declared.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a subclass of any parent class - in this case MyDBHandler and SQLiteOpenHelper respectively, you must first create an instance of the parent class. In order to do this, the first line of your constructor, must call the constructor of the parent.

in `public MyDBHandler(){}` you do not do this.

At the very least you will need to get a reference to a context so that it can be passed to the parent. The rest of the arguments are definable from your constructor, or can be null.

Here is an example from one of my projects. NAME and VERSION are class constants. Name is a String that is the name of the database file, and Version is an int specifying the current version number of your database schema.

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, NAME, null, VERSION);
}
```

So you can either remove the no argument constructor `public MyDBHandler(){}`, and use the other constructor that you have, or modify it so that it calls the superclass constructor similar to the example above.